# What is the most elegant way to integrate jQuery plugins in an Angular app?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I've recently started learning Angular.js and I'm trying not to use the framework in the wrong way and cause myself problems later on.

What's confusing me right now is that I'm trying to use a jQuery plugin, [MediaElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) and it's not clear to me what the most elegant way to integrate it. So far everything I've tried doesn't feel quite right and when I can make it work, I'm still not able to control the plugin from other parts of the app.

I've been trying the following 2 ways of doing this:

1) Create a directive. The directive's link function then contains a call to the function which turns that element into a media player with standard controls, like this:

```
$(element).mediaelementplayer();
```

The main problem with this way of doing it is that although I can conveniently create the media player control, I can't see how I can control it with the app - I want to be able to control playback from elsewhere within my app.

2) Another way to do it would be to create a new MediaElementPlayer object in the controller and add it to the scope object.

```
$scope.player = new MediaElementPlayer();
```

By doing it this way I would assume I should be able to control playback by calling relevant methods on the object. But this seems wrong - it seems to make more sense to use a directive so that I can reuse it. Also, if I do it like this then you can't see the playback controls and the playback progress bar, with the first solution you can.

What is the best way to do this? Is there any way to create the player using the first method I've described and then control it from the main controller by assigning a reference to the scope? Is there a better way of doing this altogether?

Any tips would be much appreciated - I've spent several hours trying to get something working.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> I've recently started learning Angular.js and I'm trying not to use
>   the framework in the wrong way and cause myself problems later on.

If this is the case, you *shouldn't use jQuery plugins.*

Angular is designed to be a solution to a lot of issues caused by jQuery (i.e., code spaghetti.)

Instead of a jQuery plugin, you should implement the appropriate *angular plugin.*

In the case of audio, there is ng-audio.

https://github.com/danielstern/ngAudio

Disclaimer: I am head contributor of ng-audio

Comment: I think I had a look at this earlier today - I think my main concern was that I couldn't find a way to get or set the elapsed time using ngAudio. This was one of the reasons I was trying to work with the jQuery plugin. Can ngAudio do this?

Comment: @gonogo If there's a feature you'd like to see please develop it and then make a pull request

Answer (score 1):

Your directive should set up events that it listens for such as play, pause, etc. Then the other parts of the app could $broadcast these events (likely on $rootScope)

```
function link(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
  var player = $(iElement).mediaelementplayer();

  var deregisterPlay = scope.$on('media:play', function() {
    player.play();
  }
  //etc.

  iElement.on('$destroy', function() {
    deregisterPlay();
  }
}
```

Comment: This hadn't occurred to me. So if I understand this correctly, the call to $(iElement).mediaelementplayer() should return an object I can then use (it will also put the play/pause controls on the element as shown in my example (1) ). Then the call to scope.$on registers an event  handler called 'media:play' and returns a deregistration function which I can call if and when the element is destroyed. I presume I can then emit these events using the jQuery trigger function. Have I understood this correctly? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @gonogo Yes, I made some assumptions based on how jQuery plugins typically work. They typically return a jQuery object that wraps the element. If this is not the case for this particular plugin, modify based on how it does work. As far as the deregistration, this is a common pattern when setting up listeners.